# How to wait for thread to finished in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets

How to wait for thread to finish for starting new thread which is dependent on previous thread in android??

Consider that I have 2 thread thread1 and thread2. In thread1 I performed writing task on socket and in thread2 I perforem reading task of socket.
After writing on socket I have to wait for sometime as the client need to process the data and respond back after that reading process will be initiate. So how to ensure that writing on the socket is complete and reading from socket is complete.

here is the thread code im using,

```
class Thread1 implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);
            output =  socket.getOutputStream();
            input = socket.getInputStream();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //tvMessage.setText("Connected\n");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Write_Thread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            output.write(output_array,0,data_length);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

class Read_Thread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                rec_count = input.read(input_array);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I am calling those read and write threads in the onclick listener of the button.

Comment: Why not just use one thread instead of two?  If you need to write data, then read a response there's no reason to make that two threads.  Its not like you can start reading while writing and get parallelism.

Comment: Yes, but my response is depend on data send so can't read while writing. Also response is generated after some milliseconds as my controller takes time to process the query. It's in query formate and after receiving data I need to check CRC of the data as query received correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you can read about join(). or you can make a callback function that called when writing is finished and pass this callback function to the first thread that writes data.

something like this

```
class WritingThread extends Thread {
private OnWritingCompleted callback;

public WritingThread(OnWritingCompleted callback){
this.callback = callback;
}

}
```

```
interface OnWritingCompleted {
void onCompleted()
}
```

you can pass this callback function to desired there like this

```
new WritingThread(new OnWritingCompleted { 
    override void onCompleted() {
    // start reading thread here 
    }
})
```

when the writing finished just do this

```
callback.onCompleted()
```

Comment: I came across join() but I can't find a example used in android. I have tried it in android but I'm new to java and android so not able to make it. I can use the callback you suggested but how do I know is my socket reading or writing is completed. Also I have observed using debugger in android studio that my breakpoint is repeatedly hit in read thread, also read socket return the number of byte read sometimes I get value in readcount but there is no data in buffer.

Comment: please show your writing and reading threads code, in this way  I can help you,
now problem it's like blackbox

Comment: Hi, I think InputStream.read or OutputStream.write are synchronized, which means after that lines of code the read or write process has completed, you can call callback function just after output.write to notify write process has completed

Comment: ill try it, but after i removed the while loop in read thread it working i dont know how, and im not accepting the solution unless im sure how it work. Right now it is working with the PC communication. lets see if it still works with my Embedded board as it takes longer times to respond back. Ill post the result/problem once i get the hands on my board,Till then Have a nice day and thank you for u r support.